# Javascript run script every 300 seconds

Tags: javascript

I have the following code that displays a php file on my page. But I was hoping someone could help me out so that the code refreshes every 300 seconds

```
httpRequest("recent-widget.php", showrecent);
function showrecent(WIDGET){
 d = document.getElementById('recent-widget');
 d.innerHTML = WIDGET;
}

function httpRequest(url, callback) {
  var httpObj = false;
  if (typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined') {
    httpObj = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    try{
      httpObj = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
    } catch(e) {
      try{
        httpObj = new ActiveXObject('iMicrosoft.XMLHTTP');
      } catch(e) {}
    }
  }
  if (!httpObj) return;
  httpObj.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (httpObj.readyState == 4) { // when request is complete
      callback(httpObj.responseText);
    }
  };
  httpObj.open('GET', url, true);
  httpObj.send(null);
}
```

Comment: Did you try setInterval?

Comment: I highly recommend you use a library for your AJAX needs (like jQuery).

Comment: put all that in a function, call it once, then use `setInterval` to call it every 300 seconds. if you want to reload the entire page, just call `window.reload` using `setTimeout`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply use `setInterval` to repeat the call you make in the top every 300000 milliseconds.  For example

```
setInterval(function() {
   httpRequest("recent-widget.php", showrecent);
}, 300000);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do:

```
setInterval(function() {
    httpRequest("recent-widget.php", showrecent)
} , 300000);
```

Comment: That is incorrect - `httpRequest()` will get executed immediately there, isntead of on the schedule.  You need to wrap it in a `function(){}`

Comment: Ahh, thanks Matt! I've fixed the answer. Slipped my mind for a few minutes :\